# Why it is not showing Error when I use dtype=str as argument in Series and passing data as a list of Strings and Floating point numbers.?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis

when I am writing code it seems like pandas Series are supporting different data types.
Which concept I am missing I this code..??

This dosent shows error

```
import pandas as pd
d=["javeed","meera","shareef",1.12]
pd.Series(d,range(1,5),dtype=str)
```

This shows Error:

```
i=[1,2,3,4,"Javeed"]
pd.Series(i,range(1,6),dtype=int)
```

I expected error for both cells but it is showing error for only one cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one will not give you error because `1.12` will be converted to string as you mentioned `dtype = str` while making series.

```
import pandas as pd
d=["javeed","meera","shareef",1.12]
sr = pd.Series(d,range(1,5),dtype=str)

print(sr[4])
print(type(sr[4]))
```

Output:

```
1.12   # this is string here
<class 'str'>
```

Reason: A `float` can be cast to `string` while a `string` can not be cast to `float`.

In second series, you have `strings` but you are mentioning `dtype = int` and since `strings` can't be cast into `int` so it is giving you error.